# Can not find linspace in python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Just like in python2, I did the following:

```
import numpy as np
print (np.linspace(2, 3, 4))
```

Got error:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'linspace'`

So where do I find `linspace()`

Comment: Double check to make sure you don't have a python file named `numpy.py` in your working directory. it could also be a folder named `numpy`. That may be what is being imported rather than the `numpy` package.

Comment: You might want to `print(np.__file__)` and see if that's really the numpy package there.

Comment: @MSeifert I tried `print (np._file_)`, but it said `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: @Abdou I'm sure there is no `numpy.py` in the working directory.

Comment: I installed the numpy through brew. I used two different versions of numpy, one came with the default python-2 in my computer, and the other was installed through brew.

Comment: I also tried other functions, `np.sin(2)`, but was thrown the same error `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'sin'`.

Comment: What do you see when you run `np.__path__`?

Comment: @Abdou It returns `_NamespacePath(['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'])`

Comment: That's very strange. I would use `pip` to reinstall the package. Run `sudo python3.6 -m pip install -I numpy` and enter your password when prompted. This still remains very strange.

Comment: @Abdou Thanks, your approach works!

Answer (score 1):

As [@Abdou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3135417/abdou) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576132/can-not-find-linspace-in-python3#comment78118475_45576132),  the problem was solved when I reinstalled `numpy`:

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install -I numpy
```